# How to refer to list during with_dict loop

Tags: loops, ansible, registry

I am trying to build playbook that dynamically queries Windows' registry to detect installed instances of SQL Server (or anything else), its version, location, etc. and do X action for every instance. This works ok if only one SQL instance is installed but I am not sure how to achieve this in multi-instance environment as I am mixing dicts and list and I am not sure how to solve this..

As a simple example playbook below detects installed SQL instances based on reg keys and checks version of SQL for each instance. I would like to out the info on per instance basis (or even better put this into dict variable so I can use it later and add more details based on other reg keys).

Problem is that some of the returned data is a list and I am not sure how to add it to the loop (or add it to dict where key is the instance for example).

Code:

```
- name: 'Go to Windows registry and check if any SQL instance is installed - using win_reg_stat module'
  win_reg_stat:
    path: HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL
  register: reg_InstalledInstances

- name: 'Go to Windows registry and for each installed instance get its version number'
  win_reg_stat:
    path: HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\{{item.value.raw_value}}\MSSQLServer\CurrentVersion
    name: CurrentVersion
  with_dict: '{{reg_InstalledInstances.properties}}'
  register: reg_CurrentVersion

- debug:
    msg:
    - '{{reg_CurrentVersion}}'

- name: 'Show all the details'
  debug:
    msg:
    - 'Hostname: {{inventory_hostname}}'
    - 'SQL Instance: {{item.key}}'
    - 'SQL Instance in Registry: {{item.value.raw_value}}'
    #- 'CurrentVersion: {{reg_CurrentVersion.results.raw_value}}'
  with_dict: '{{reg_InstalledInstances.properties}}'

- name:
  debug:
    msg:
    - '{{reg_CurrentVersion}}'
```

Problem:
I am not sure how to refer reg_CurrentVersion into the loop - in the loop (i tried  {{reg_CurrentVersion.results.item.raw_value}} as well):

```
...
    - 'CurrentVersion: {{reg_CurrentVersion.results.raw_value}}'
  with_dict: '{{reg_InstalledInstances.properties}}'
```

results in:

```
the task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'list object' has no attribute 'raw_value'
```

reg_CurrentVersion on its own works fine and looks like this:

```
ok: [gbltcdevcmdr01] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "changed": false,
            "msg": "All items completed",
            "results": [
                {
                    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                    "changed": false,
                    "exists": true,
                    "failed": false,
                    "item": {
                        "key": "SQL2014",
                        "value": {
                            "raw_value": "MSSQL12.SQL2014",
                            "type": "REG_SZ",
                            "value": "MSSQL12.SQL2014"
                        }
                    },
                    "raw_value": "12.0.6024.0",
                    "type": "REG_SZ",
                    "value": "12.0.6024.0"
                },
                {
                    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                    "changed": false,
                    "exists": true,
                    "failed": false,
                    "item": {
                        "key": "SQL2016",
                        "value": {
                            "raw_value": "MSSQL13.SQL2016",
                            "type": "REG_SZ",
                            "value": "MSSQL13.SQL2016"
                        }
                    },
                    "raw_value": "13.2.5026.0",
                    "type": "REG_SZ",
                    "value": "13.2.5026.0"
                },
                {
                    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                    "changed": false,
                    "exists": true,
                    "failed": false,
                    "item": {
                        "key": "MSSQLSERVER",
                        "value": {
                            "raw_value": "MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER",
                            "type": "REG_SZ",
                            "value": "MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER"
                        }
                    },
                    "raw_value": "11.0.7001.0",
                    "type": "REG_SZ",
                    "value": "11.0.7001.0"
                },
                {
                    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                    "changed": false,
                    "exists": true,
                    "failed": false,
                    "item": {
                        "key": "SQL2017",
                        "value": {
                            "raw_value": "MSSQL14.SQL2017",
                            "type": "REG_SZ",
                            "value": "MSSQL14.SQL2017"
                        }
                    },
                    "raw_value": "14.0.1000.169",
                    "type": "REG_SZ",
                    "value": "14.0.1000.169"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

EDIT:

at the moment if I run the initial code:

```
...
- name: 'Show all the details'
  debug:
    msg:
    - 'Hostname: {{inventory_hostname}}'
    - 'SQL Instance: {{item.key}}'
    - 'SQL Instance in Registry: {{item.value.raw_value}}'
    #- 'CurrentVersion: {{reg_CurrentVersion.results.raw_value}}'
  with_dict: '{{reg_InstalledInstances.properties}}'
```

I got this:

```
ok: [testhost] => (item={'key': 'SQL2014', 'value': {'raw_value': 'MSSQL12.SQL2014', 'value': 'MSSQL12.SQL2014', 'type': 'REG_SZ'}}) => {
    "msg": [
        "Hostname: testhost",
        "SQL Instance: SQL2014",
        "SQL Instance in Registry: MSSQL12.SQL2014"
    ]
}
ok: [testhost] => (item={'key': 'SQL2016', 'value': {'raw_value': 'MSSQL13.SQL2016', 'value': 'MSSQL13.SQL2016', 'type': 'REG_SZ'}}) => {
    "msg": [
        "Hostname: testhost",
        "SQL Instance: SQL2016",
        "SQL Instance in Registry: MSSQL13.SQL2016"
    ]
}
ok: [testhost] => (item={'key': 'MSSQLSERVER', 'value': {'raw_value': 'MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER', 'value': 'MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER', 'type': 'REG_SZ'}}) => {
    "msg": [
        "Hostname: testhost",
        "SQL Instance: MSSQLSERVER",
        "SQL Instance in Registry: MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER"
    ]
}
ok: [testhost] => (item={'key': 'SQL2017', 'value': {'raw_value': 'MSSQL14.SQL2017', 'value': 'MSSQL14.SQL2017', 'type': 'REG_SZ'}}) => {
    "msg": [
        "Hostname: testhost",
        "SQL Instance: SQL2017",
        "SQL Instance in Registry: MSSQL14.SQL2017"
    ]
}
```

I would like to simply add reg_CurrentVersion.results.raw_value as an extra line for each instance. Something like below:

```
ok: [testhost] => (item={'key': 'SQL2014', 'value': {'raw_value': 'MSSQL12.SQL2014', 'value': 'MSSQL12.SQL2014', 'type': 'REG_SZ'}}) => {
    "msg": [
        "Hostname: testhost",
        "SQL Instance: SQL2014",
        "SQL Instance in Registry: MSSQL12.SQL2014"
        "CurrentVersion: 12.0.6024.0"
    ]
}
ok: [testhost] => (item={'key': 'SQL2016', 'value': {'raw_value': 'MSSQL13.SQL2016', 'value': 'MSSQL13.SQL2016', 'type': 'REG_SZ'}}) => {
    "msg": [
        "Hostname: testhost",
        "SQL Instance: SQL2016",
        "SQL Instance in Registry: MSSQL13.SQL2016"
        "CurrentVersion: 13.2.5026.0"
    ]
}
ok: [testhost] => (item={'key': 'MSSQLSERVER', 'value': {'raw_value': 'MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER', 'value': 'MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER', 'type': 'REG_SZ'}}) => {
    "msg": [
        "Hostname: testhost",
        "SQL Instance: MSSQLSERVER",
        "SQL Instance in Registry: MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER"
        "CurrentVersion: 11.0.7001.0"
    ]
}
ok: [testhost] => (item={'key': 'SQL2017', 'value': {'raw_value': 'MSSQL14.SQL2017', 'value': 'MSSQL14.SQL2017', 'type': 'REG_SZ'}}) => {
    "msg": [
        "Hostname: testhost",
        "SQL Instance: SQL2017",
        "SQL Instance in Registry: MSSQL14.SQL2017"
        "CurrentVersion: 14.0.1000.169"
    ]
}
```

PS. Is there a way to build dict and append new values to it later on?

Tomasz

Comment: What result do you expect?

Comment: I have updated the question to show current and desired output.

Answer (score 1):

> Q: *"Is there a way to build a dictionary and append new values to it later on?"*

A: Yes. It's possible. Let's create the dictionary with the data

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        mylist: "{{ reg_CurrentVersion.results|
                    json_query('[].{instance: item.key,
                                    registry: item.value.raw_value,
                                    version: raw_value}') }}"
    - debug:
        var: mylist
```

gives

```yaml
    "mylist": [
        {
            "instance": "SQL2014", 
            "registry": "MSSQL12.SQL2014", 
            "version": "12.0.6024.0"
        }, 
        {
            "instance": "SQL2016", 
            "registry": "MSSQL13.SQL2016", 
            "version": "13.2.5026.0"
        }, 
        {
            "instance": "MSSQLSERVER", 
            "registry": "MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER", 
            "version": "11.0.7001.0"
        }, 
        {
            "instance": "SQL2017", 
            "registry": "MSSQL14.SQL2017", 
            "version": "14.0.1000.169"
        }
    ]
```

Append hostname to each dictionary

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        mylist2: "{{ mylist2|default([]) +
                     [item|combine({'hostname': inventory_hostname})] }}"
      loop: "{{ mylist }}"
    - debug:
        var: mylist2
```

gives

```yaml
    "mylist2": [
        {
            "hostname": "localhost", 
            "instance": "SQL2014", 
            "registry": "MSSQL12.SQL2014", 
            "version": "12.0.6024.0"
        }, 
        {
            "hostname": "localhost", 
            "instance": "SQL2016", 
            "registry": "MSSQL13.SQL2016", 
            "version": "13.2.5026.0"
        }, 
        {
            "hostname": "localhost", 
            "instance": "MSSQLSERVER", 
            "registry": "MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER", 
            "version": "11.0.7001.0"
        }, 
        {
            "hostname": "localhost", 
            "instance": "SQL2017", 
            "registry": "MSSQL14.SQL2017", 
            "version": "14.0.1000.169"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: thanks and apologies for slow reply.. I will give it a go in coming days and read up about the commands to learn something new. I will keep you posted with the progress. Tomasz